# Как переключить Git GUI с русского на английский?

Tags: git

Как переключить язык интерфейса Git GUI с русского на английский?

Comment: никак. он только на инглише и еще паре языков.

А зачем вопрос? что там есть непонятного в интерфейсе?

Comment: Я не могу понять, что означают пункты меню на русском языке. Слова понимаю, а общий смысл - нет. Невозможно воспринимать в русском переводе такие термины, как commit, branch, log и прочие. Они имеют смысл только на английском.

Answer (score 2):

Запускать из консоли вот так:

```
LANG=C git gui
```

Comment: E:\>LANG=C git gui
""LANG=C"" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: @dmitry_ii, это в bush (в \*nix) надо вводить.

А у Вас, что, винда?

Comment: Да. Семёрка.

Comment: В следующий раз, в вопросе указывайте, какую ОС используете.

Наверное проще всего снести и переустановить с английским.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот тебе ответ](http://git-scm.com/book/ru)

А по поводу непонимания, тут вряд ли поможет перевод.

Comment: Перевод не помогает, он реально мешает. С дуру выбрал при установке русский язык, теперь не знаю как избавиться.

Comment: переустанови, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

пойти в папку "c:\Program Files\Git\share\git-gui\lib\msgs" или где там он установлен
найти файл ru.msg и переименовать например в ru.msg_
а смысл в том, что если оболочке не находит файл языка под текущие настройки пользователя, то она стартует на английском

да, интерфейс оболочки ужасен и настройка языка иным способом вообще не предусмотрена

Answer (score 1):

System | Advanced System Settings | Environment Variables

LANG = C

Answer (score 0):

В папке, куда установлен `git` нужно удалить или переименовать файл `ru.msg` в `git/share/git-gui/lib/msgs`

Answer (score 0):

Проверенный и **работающий** вариант для Mac Os - запускать через `LC_MESSAGES=C git`

Не нужно никаких LANG=C или LC_ALL=C, удалять или переименовывать файлы тоже.

Можно в `~/.bash_profile` написать `alias git='LC_MESSAGES=C git'` и потом перезапустить терминал.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте эти строки в `~/.bashrc` или `~/.bash_profile`, чтобы заставить git отображать все сообщения на английском языке:

```
# Set Git language to English
#alias git='LANG=en_US git'
alias git='LANG=en_GB git'
```

Источник: https://progi.pro/kak-izmenit-yazik-interfeysa-komandnoy-stroki-git-4890125